# Can Visual Studio create a report for solution builds?

Tags: visual-studio, report, code-analysis, building

I know that Visual studio will create a little webpage if a project upgrade/migration fails and show that to the user. Is there a way to get Visual Studio to create a similar **report for solution builds**?

So something which lists all Warnings, Errors and Info Messages that the compiler spits out similar to the Error window inside Visual Studio itself.

Comment: The upgrade "little website" is just an HTML file, no website. It seems like you would be better looking at a CI/CD pipeline service which typically have a Website for a UI.

Comment: A website can be just a single file :) 
I have CI/CD but I still need a build report mechanism. Yes It'll tell me how many tests failed or if a build has passed but the errors and warnings that don't cause the built to fail entirely are lost and It would be nice to get them out without having to write a parser for the compiler output.